# How do data types work with scipy.linalg.get_blas_functions?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I am exploring the scipy.linalg.get_blas_function() method in python. But I am noticing some difficulties it has in handling numpy int types.

**Input**

```
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np

def blas(name, ndarray):
    arr = scipy.linalg.get_blas_funcs((name,), (ndarray,), dtype=ndarray.dtype)[0]
    return arr

blas_scal = blas('scal', np.array([], dtype=np.int32))
print "int32 --> %s" % (blas_scal.dtype)

blas_scal = blas('scal', np.array([], dtype=np.int64))
print "int64 --> %s" % (blas_scal.dtype)

blas_scal = blas('scal', np.array([], dtype=np.float32))
print "float32 --> %s" % (blas_scal.dtype)

blas_scal = blas('scal', np.array([], dtype=np.float64))
print "float64 --> %s" % (blas_scal.dtype)
```

**Output**

```
int32 --> float64
int64 --> float64
float32 --> float32
float64 --> float64
```

As you can see, the get_blas_funcs() seems to ignore the data type when it is an integer, and outputs float64 whenever you have any sort of numpy integer. However, inputting a numpy float32 or numpy64 is fine with get_blas_funcs(), and it doesn't change the dtype as it goes through to output.

What is happening here?
How does this function handle data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general comments:

- BLAS is more a specification than a library

  - There are many implementations (Atlas, OpenBLAS, MKL), all more or less working on the same interface
- **BLAS is all about floating-point math**

  - The available prefixes decide about the type in use ([see top left](http://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/becker/blasqr_betterFonts.pdf))
  - There is *S: single-precision, D: double-precision, C complex single-precision and Z complex double-precision*

    - ([sometimes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-naming-conventions-for-blas-routines) mixed types are supported like: CS, ZD)

      - *For example, the function scasum uses a complex input array and returns a real value.* (link above)
  - **In general there is no support for integer types!**

    - There seems to be some ideas to support those (links: [1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/720664), [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openblas-users/tiPoyQtM-VU)), but it surely is not common (and maybe there is no robust / well-tested support yet)
    - I'm pretty sure there is no single integer-like BLAS usage in any of those big libs (numpy, scipy, sklearn, pandas), which of course would be hard without a standard supported by all possible BLAS-backends (as i said: multiple candidates!)
- This implies: **you are asking for a function, which is not available** (scal with integer-like types)

  - This means: casting needs to be done!
  - **What kind of casting is done, is a design-decision**:

    - Here it **seems** (probably easy to check the code if needed):

      - If type one of the supported ones, keep it

        - float32 -> float32 (S -> S)
        - float64 -> float 64 (D -> D)
      - If not: cast to double-precision / D (more or less default in numpy/scipy!; more common than single-precision; at least nowadays!)
- Using BLAS is very low-level and everyone trying to do it needs to be sure to understand what's needed to do it right (not only types; but also memory layout)!

  - Compare with [scipy's warning](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.blas.html): *Warning
    These functions do little to no error checking. It is possible to cause crashes by mis-using them, so prefer using the higher-level routines in scipy.linalg.*
- Somewhat related question here (showing the implications of these missing features): [Why is it faster to perform float by float matrix multiplication compared to int by int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373679/why-is-it-faster-to-perform-float-by-float-matrix-multiplication-compared-to-int/45373748)

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer. I've not done 'casting' before, would you mind providing some links to useful educational pages for it?

Comment: Ah, casting is just the movement between different data types.