# C++ how to set environment variable so OpenBLAS runs multithreaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, openblas

The author recommends the following:
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS

```
Setting the number of threads using environment variables

Environment variables are used to specify a maximum number of threads. For example,

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4
export GOTO_NUM_THREADS=4
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

The priorities are OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS > GOTO_NUM_THREADS > OMP_NUM_THREADS.

If you compile this library with USE_OPENMP=1, you should set the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable; OpenBLAS ignores OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS and GOTO_NUM_THREADS when compiled with USE_OPENMP=1.
```

When I use "export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=16" in my main.cpp, I get an error about templates.

So, I changed my CMakeList.txt file to include:

```
set($ENV{OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS} 16)
```

This seemed to have no effect on the threading of my application. I only see 1 CPU core at 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I use "export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=16" in my main.cpp, I get an error about templates.

`OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` is a runtime defined variable so it should not impact the build of an application unless the build scripts explicitly use this variable which is very unusual and a very bad idea (since the compile-time environment can be different from the run-time one).

Note that `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=16` is a **bash command** and not something to put in a C++ file. Its purpose is to set the environment variable `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` so it can be read at runtime by OpenBLAS when your application call a BLAS function. You should do something like:

```bash
# Build part
cmake  # with the correct parameters
make

# Running part
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4
./your_application  # with the correct parameters

# Alternative solution:
# OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4 ./your_application
```

> So, I changed my CMakeList.txt file to include:

This should have not effect indeed because the variable should not be used at compile time.

> I only see 1 CPU core at 100%

Note that setting `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` may not be enough to use multiple threads in practice. If your matrices are small, then consider reading this [very-recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72663092) about how OpenBLAS works with multiple threads.